# Finding genealogy research companies offering their service in Poland?

Tags: poland

I am interested in finding out more about my family genealogy by hiring some company or person to do the work for me. My entire family comes from Poland, so I am wondering whether there are any companies offering genealogy research services in that country? I'm having a hard time finding any.

Comment: If your question would be better if it included a specific location or locations in Poland and more specific time periods. Without these specifics, it has the feel of a "list" question. See http://meta.genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/89/how-can-we-word-the-faqs-to-make-clear-the-site-policy-on-list-questions

Comment: You should also clarify whether your ancestors were Jewish or not, as that will make a big difference about the kinds of records that are available, how one goes about getting them, and potentially the degree of cooperation you might expect.

Comment: Also suggest the sort of time frame?

Answer (score 9):

What is also definitely worth doing in addition is to include as much of your Polish tree as possible on match-providing sites. [Ancestry.com](http://www.ancestry.com/) is the largest one globally, but not popular in Poland, since it still lacks a Polish-language version. Largest ones in Poland are [MyHeritage.com](http://www.myheritage.com) and [Geni](http://www.geni.com), in that order. Especially MyHeritage is very likely to produce matches with existing genealogy trees, providing a great starting point for communicating with existing detached family.

Answer (score 8):

Cyndi's List at [lists some professional groups located in Poland](http://www.cyndislist.com/poland/professionals/) (including A.A. Watta & Co. and Discover Polish Ancestors).  You might also consider contacting the [Polish Genealogical Society of America](http://www.pgsa.org/index.php?) to see if anyone there can give you feedback on any company or person you think about hiring.

Answer (score 8):

Have a look at [Polish Origins](http://polishorigins.com/document/home_page). They have a forum for questions and offer research and also genealogical trips. They helped me when I went to Poland a couple of years ago. All in English too and there are even SKS who do translations of the forum too.

Answer (score 3):

I run a small genealogy research bureau in Poland. I am a member of Polish Genealogy Society and lately I placed TOP10 genealogists in Poland in latin and german documents reading.

We are a small family bureau and our philosophy is to give you not only names, dates and places but to rebuild your family history. We always try to find out our clients' ancestors' occupation, wealth, purposes for their decisions. Our costs are lower because we live in Poland and don't have to organize expensive journeys to receive documents and records.

To find out more, visit our website: http://www.genealogiapolonica.com/.

Comment: Welcome to Genealogy SE! Per the [FAQ](http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures), I've removed your signature. Because your posts are always pre-signed with your user-card, there's no need to re-sign them. You can, however, put whatever information you want in your profile. To do so, simply click the [edit button](http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/users/edit/734) in your profile. Again, welcome to GFH.SE!