# Tracing genealogy of people with particular Polish surname?

Tags: surnames, poland

I am trying to trace the genealogy of one or more people with the surname "Wozniack."

I believe that it is Polish name and that these people are of Polish descent

Where in Poland are people with this surname likely to be found/come from?

If I took a field trip over to Poland, what resources might be available  there for tracing them that would not be available to me now (sitting at a desk, working online, in the U.S.)?

Comment: There's already a question about tracking your Polish family that might be useful for you: http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/1475/382

Comment: @skolima You are right - that certainly looks like a near duplicate for the second question within this Question, and has some great resources listed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just checked [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wo%C5%BAniak) and found that Wozniak is the "tenth most common surname in Poland (89,015 people in 2009)" and, as a result, I suspect you will find people of that name (and its variants) spread all over Poland.

Consequently, there will be a vast number of potential resources that you could use to try and trace people with this name (and its variants), and the place I would start looking for useful resources is the [FamilySearch.org learning page on Poland](https://familysearch.org/learn/wiki/en/Poland).

Reading between the lines there, it seems that Poland's vital records become more accessible once you know the name of the town your ancestors came from and if you speak Polish.

Answer (score 3):

In Polish, the name is most likely spelt Woźniak. With a name as common as Woźniak, it will be difficult to make progress without some knowledge of the town from which the family came.

Answer (score 1):

It can also be "Woźniacki." Here is a link to the page where you can see the occurrence of a given name in Poland (of course, these are not all people): https://nazwiska-polskie.pl/Wo%C5%BAniacki, and this is the link to the same page with the name "Woźniak": https://nazwiska-polskie.pl/Wo%C5%BAniak

Comment: Alas due to the major displacement of people after 1945 it is not very useful to have a modern mapping of surnames in Poland to fin the true origin of one family... hence [that](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/9884/how-can-i-find-surname-distributions-for-names-in-poland-before-ww2) question.