# Finding surname distributions for names in Poland before WW2?

Tags: surnames, poland, gis

[Gen-evolu](http://www.gen-evolu.de) allows us to see the distribution of family names in Germany both in modern times and during the peak of the third Reich in WW2, before Germany was affected with the ethnic cleansing of its former eastern provinces. Unfortunately this information is based on Telephone books and telephone was still a luxury in the 40s so most many people didn't have one, yet this information is better than nothing.

[The Polish version of dynastree](http://www.moikrewni.pl/mapa/) allows us to see name distribution in Poland in modern times. Is there a way to see a name distribution of Poland before the country moved 250km to the West and was ethnically cleansed?

Comment: I agree it would be useful, but where would that data come from? Most _current_ Polish state records are still not digitized, and here we're talking about 100 years of historical records. A lot of them were destroyed during WW2. Others are scattered between state archives and church archives in Poland, Ukraine, Belarus, Lithuania, Russia...

Comment: @skolima Yeah that suck so much. :( Telephone was probably even less common in Poland than in Germany so that won't help.

Comment: @skolima Wasn't there a full census in the 30s in Poland ?

Comment: In '21 and '31, but it was for statistical purposes. As far as I can check, personal details such as name were not recorded.

Comment: Usually for such times the best source is WWI or WWII casulaty or service record. There are records online for France and Belgium that I know of. At a glance I can't see much for Poland. Maybe: http://www.straty.pl/index.php/pl/szukaj-w-bazie